# Form table wide space between label and input text box

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

There is something wrong with the design of my form as shown below.

[image]

```
<div class="myRegInfoForm">
            <form method="POST" action="action_reg.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="regname" value="" id="regname" required pattern="[A-Za-z_ ]{1,}" title="Only letters allowed."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Course applied for: </label>
                            <label><?php echo $CourseName ?></label>

                </table>
            </form>
    </div>
```

A wide space is between the label and input text box after adding the second `<td>` element and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me?

```
.myRegInfoForm {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

My desired output:

[image]

Comment: Your desired output doesn't include the "Course applied for:" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `text-align` for the `td` to `right`

```css
.myRegInfoForm {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.myRegInfoForm td{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="myRegInfoForm">
            <form method="POST" action="action_reg.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="regname" value="" id="regname" required pattern="[A-Za-z_ ]{1,}" title="Only letters allowed."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Course applied for: </label>
                            <label><?php echo $CourseName ?></label>

                </table>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `colspan="2"` to the td in the second row, as shown below. The width of the first td in the first row automatically expands to match the width of the first td in the second row, but by setting the `colspan` you can have that cell span across the width of both cells in the first row.

```html
<div class="myRegInfoForm">
  <form method="POST" action="action_reg.php">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="regname" value="" id="regname" required pattern="[A-Za-z_ ]{1,}" title="Only letters allowed." />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <label>Course applied for:</label>
          <label>
            <?php echo $CourseName ?>
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Or, better, don't use a table for this, since you don't seem to want a tabular layout.

Comment: Hi, much thanks for the quick response. What should I use if I want to create a simple "contact form"?

Comment: There's no one right way. If you have multiple inputs and you want them to all be left-aligned then a table is probably they easiest way (using the `text-align: right` property on the labels as in [z0mBi3's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39113767/615754). Some people just use label elements with CSS to set them as block elements with the required width. Some people use ul elements with an li per field, styled to not look like dot points. Some people just use paragraphs. Etc.

Answer (score 0):

since u have another td, so the td will autosize himself.
so u need to use float:right in label;

```
<td><label style="float:right;">Name: </label></td>
```

i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the closing tag for your second tr. Neither for the last td.

```
<div class="myRegInfoForm">
            <form method="POST" action="action_reg.php">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Name: </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="regname" value="" id="regname" required pattern="[A-Za-z_ ]{1,}" title="Only letters allowed."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    **<tr>
                        <td>**
                            <label>Course applied for: </label>
                            <label><?php echo $CourseName ?></label>

                </table>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your input with in the same `td` tags. Like this:

```
<td>
  <label style="display:inline-block;">Name: </label>
  <input type="text" name="regname" value="" id="regname" required pattern="[A-Za-z_ ]{1,}" title="Only letters allowed."/>
</td>
```